# Is needed Return value or not?, Working with try, catch and Finally: Java

Tags: java, return, try-catch-finally

I have this code:

```
private String Style(String Arg, Vector VctrClass) throws Exception {
  if (Verify that Arg is contained into VctrClass)) {
    return "Something";
  } else {
    throw new Exception("Error The argument required \""+Arg+"\" doesn't exist<br>");
  }
}
```

Here my problem, I had this method:

```
public String GetStylString(String Arg) {
  try {
    return this.Style(Arg,OneVector);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
  finally {
    return "";
  }
}
```

But' I have this message:
**Void methods cannot return a value**

Then I changed my method to:

```
public String GetStylString(String Arg) {
  try {
    return this.Style(Arg,OneVector);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
}
```

I have this message:
**This method must return a result of type String**

Comment: (a) You didn't get the message about 'void methods cannot return a value' from the code you posted: there are no `void` methods present. (b) You would be better off not catching the exception at all and letting it propagate. (c) You certainly shouldn't just catch `Exception` at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Add the return after the println, not in the finally:

```
public String GetStylString(String Arg) {
  try {
    return this.Style(Arg,OneVector);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    return "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the return after the catch instead of in the finally:

```
public String GetStylString(String Arg) {
  try {
    return this.Style(Arg,OneVector);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
  return "";
}
```